# Is there a way to make music play seemlessly in certain scenes and pause in others in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game where i want in some scenes to play music across them seemlessly and to make the music pause when i get out of these scenes and to resume automatically when iget back to them.

i've tried making a list (array) of the scenes i want to play the music in and check the name of the current scene to see if it is on the list or not.but it doesnt work when i type .contains to check the answer.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DontDestroy : MonoBehaviour {
void Awake(){
        print ("WoW");
        GameObject[] objs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag 
("music");
        if (objs.Length > 1) 
        {
         Destroy (this.gameObject);
        }
        DontDestroyOnLoad (this.gameObject);
     }      
}
```

i use this to keep music playing when switching scenes and not to make it duplicate when i return to the original scene. how ever i want it to work in a certain number of scenes.

Answer (score 0):

First I would use a Singleton pattern instead of allways using `Find`

Than register a listener to [`SceneManager.sceneLoaded`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html)

Finally I would simply have a list of scenes to check if the loaded scene should play Musik or not

```
public class PlayMusik : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static PlayMusik Singleton;

    // Here you reference the secenes where music should be playing
    public List<Scene> scenesWithMusik;

    // Flag to control of music is playing
    private bool isPlayingMusik;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        if(Singleton)
        {
            Debug.Log("Already another PlayMusik in Scene.", Singleton);
            Debug.Log("Destroying this one", this);

            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }

        Singleton = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

        // Make sure listener is only added once
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    private void OnDestroy ()
    {
        // Cleanup listener
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    // Called when a scene is loaded
    void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnSceneLoaded: " + scene.name);
        Debug.Log(mode);

        // here you handle what should happen with the music e.g.
        // if the loaded scene is in scenesWithMusic enable music
        // (What should happen if you load a scene additive is up to you)
        if(scenesWithMusik.Contains(scene))
        {
            if(!isPlayingMusik)
            {
                //Todo: Enable Music here!

                isPlayingMusik = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(isPlayingMusik)
            {
                //Todo: Stop Music here!

                isPlayingMusik = false;
            }  
        }
    }
}
```